# What is the congruence class of $x^3\mod x^3+x+1$?

Tags: polynomials, equivalence-relations, polynomial-congruences

I have a given Polynom congruence with a Polynom $x^3+x+1$ ... so the set of the congruence classes is $\{0, 1,x,x+1,x^2,x^2+1,x^2+x,x^2+x+1\}$

But what would look this like? 
$$x^3\mod x^3+x+1\equiv ?$$
I think the result must be one of the congruence classes of the set, mentioned above, but I cannot figure out which one.

Comment: Are you working over $\Bbb Z/(2)$?

Comment: Hint: the result (or *remainder*) is a polynom of degree < 3 (the degree of modulus), of the form $R = x^3 - P \cdot (x^3+x+1)$, with some polynomial P. If you want the whole congruence class, it's $\{R + P \cdot (x^3+x+1) | P \in \mathbb{K}[x] \}$ where $\mathbb{K}$ is you base field.

Comment: @Pedro yes.. i didn't mentioned it, because i thought it wouldn't belong to the Task. So i think, i didn't understand Polynome congruences at all.

Comment: At least you quickly understood that you didn't understand!  Beginning of wisdom, according to Socrates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're working over $\Bbb Z/(2)$. Note that $-1=1$ there, so from $x^3+x+1\equiv 0$ you get  $x^3\equiv -x-1\equiv x+1$, that is, the class of $x^3$ is that of $1+x$.

Comment: Allright. So lets try another example, to see if i understand correctly. Lets take for instance $x^4+x$. So i would get $x^4+x\equiv x-1 \equiv x+1$ .. right?

Comment: @ToralfWestström $x^4\equiv xx^3\equiv x(x+1)\equiv x^2+x$.

Comment: Okay that makes sense for me. But it seems i am still not able to make my own calculations. So if have $x^3+x$ for example. It would be $x^3+x\equiv -1\equiv 1$ ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Downvote...? Was someone annoyed by $1=-1$?

Comment: it wasnt me. but by the way. If i have $x^3+x^2$. It would be $x^3+x^2 \equiv x^2+x+1$ right?

Comment: @ToralfWestström Yes.

Comment: Okay, but now i think i have found one, that doesnt fit the pattern. see i we take $x^3+x^2+x$ .. than it would be ...   $x^3+x^2+x\equiv x+1+x^2+x$ ... but that cannot be.

Comment: $x+x=2x=0$, @ToralfWestström, so all equal to $1+x^2$.